# Can Git-Flow and branch-per-issue workflow in JIRA work together?

Tags: eclipse, branch, jira, git-flow

Git-Flow assumes that developer creates feature branch in local repository.
Branch-per-issue workflow in JIRA assumes that developer creates feature branch in remote repository.
Can those workflows work together?
Also, will Eclipse Git-Flow plugin work with branch-per-issue workflow in JIRA?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

I just had to figure this out myself.

1. Create feature branch through JIRA

[image]
[image]

```
[sri@localhost scripts]$ git pull --all
Fetching origin
From ssh://pm.summationresearch.com:7999/l20/21-6016-xx-filesystem
 * [new branch]      feature/TX6K-188 -> origin/feature/TX6K-188
Already up to date.
[sri@localhost scripts]$ git feature list
git: 'feature' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
[sri@localhost scripts]$ git flow feature list
No feature branches exist.

You can start a new feature branch:

    git flow feature start <name> [<base>]

[sri@localhost scripts]$
```

But dag-nab-it my feature doesn't show up!

```
[sri@localhost scripts]$ git checkout -b feature/TX6K-188 remotes/origin/feature/TX6K-188
Branch 'feature/TX6K-188' set up to track remote branch 'feature/TX6K-188' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'feature/TX6K-188'
[sri@localhost scripts]$ git flow feature list
* TX6K-188
[sri@localhost scripts]$
```

**AHH!  There it is!**